# Do you know any garden planner for Mac or Web?

Tags: layout-planning

Do you know any garden planner for Mac or Web where I could make garden plans like this? Something that has free tier.

[image]

Cool feature would be if I could upload a photo like this, and it would lay out a garden with the size on the photo and the plants.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for a product that would choose the plants and create the design for you or one that has a library of plants specific to your area (or which allows you to add plants for your area) and then lets you place the plants as an overlay on a design you've already scanned or mapped out?

Comment: If planner would have a cataloge of plants I can choose from. If it would help make layouts, like drawing them it. It would be an extra to show a picture of a garden, and it would make both the layout and the plants on it. It could show a preview of the garden also.

Comment: Not sure that you'll find something like that for free.; professional apps can easily cost $500+ dollars up to well over $1000. The apps I'm familiar with have plant catalogues specific to North America, which might not be what you're looking for (although I'm guessing you'll still find lots of familiar plants in them).

Comment: Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/366/246

Answer (score 1):

Here is a page of [11 low-cost applications](https://www.techradar.com/best/best-landscape-design-software) (US sites only, but may be available elsewhere) for you to review. The reviews will give you some idea of the features available at this price tier, and clicking on the application's name should get you to an "overview" page where you can dive deeper into the product. You'll want to note that more than a few of these concentrate on hardscape, not landscape. [This is another page](https://www.thespruce.com/best-landscape-design-software-5105016) with different options; seems to be less hardscape-focused.

**Important Note!**
I have not used any of these applications and, therefore, do not recommend any specific application.

Comment: most of them are for Windows and none fo them free :(

Comment: I don't think you'll find a free product with the features you're looking for.